# Access to the post request's argument data in succeed/complete/error functions

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a bunch of jQuery AJAX post requests wrapped up in a `for` loop. Each request provides a different parameter. My question is, in the event of the request failing, how can you tell what parameter data was passed by that request?

When I try:

```
for(i = 0; i < toSubmit.length; i++) {
  $.post('doSomething.php',
         {id: toSubmit[i]},
         function(data) { /* Do something here */ },
         'json')
  .error(function() {
    console.log(toSubmit[i] + " didn't work!");
  });
}
```

...the `error` function will just output the last value in `toSubmit`, because the `i` pointer has progressed all the way through the `for` loop, while the requests are fired asynchronously. The same thing occurs in the `success` and `complete` function; the way I've got around that is to make sure the returned JSON contains the respective `id`; but if the request fails, I can't use this workaround.

Is there a way for me to get at this information, or is there a better way of firing off these requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have to set the correct context for the method call. You can look into the jQuery proxy() method which allows you to provide the correct context for the callback.

Try something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < toSubmit.length; i++) {
  var ctx = {id: i};

  $.post('doSomething.php',
         {id: toSubmit[i]},
         function(data) { /* Do something here */ },
         'json')
  .error( $.proxy(function() {
    console.log(this.id + " didn't work!");
  }, ctx) );
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
beforeSend:function(jqXHR, settings){
   jqXHR.parameters = { /* data or parameters store here*/}
}


error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
   var params = jqXHR.parameters
}
```